# Double random assignment with equal groups

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, random

I am trying to build a random sample and random assignment generator for a website I am working on that is supposed to assign randomly selected items in an equal number to a variable set of people.

For example:

In this round of assessment, we have 9 assessors, and 477 items that need to be graded by two assessors each (with the same assessor not grading the same item twice). This would come out to 954 total "assessments" that need to be made, and 106 per assessor.

Therefore I'd need an eventual list like...

```
(Item, Assessor1, Assessor2)
(1, A, B)
(2, C, D)
(3, E, F)
(4, G, H)
(5, H, B)
(6, B, F)
.
.
.
And so on
```

I've found websites that can do random number generation and even some that can do random assignment over groups, but even then I am still finding situations where the same assessor will be grading the same item throughout the results.

I am less concerned about the inherent randomness and more concerned about making sure each result list has every assessor grading the same number of items without grading the same one.

I can usually get it to the point where I have it -close- and maybe one grader will be 1 or 2 more and another will be 1 or 2 less, but unfortunately it's a hard requirement that they be equal groupings.

**EDIT**

Implemented @Tinstaafl's code and ran the following:

```
  Dim col As New MyItemCollection

    col.AddAssessor("A")
    col.AddAssessor("B")
    col.AddAssessor("C")
    col.AddAssessor("D")
    col.AddAssessor("E")
    col.AddAssessor("F")
    col.AddAssessor("G")
    col.AddAssessor("H")
    col.AddAssessor("I")

    For I As Integer = 1 To 477
        col.AddItem(I.ToString)
    Next

    Dim newList As List(Of MyItemCollection.MyItem) = col.AssignAssessors

    For Each item As MyItemCollection.MyItem In col.itemlist
        Response.Write(item.ToString & "<br/>")
    Next
```

Unfortunately my output looks like

```
1 - F - F
2 - I - I
3 - E - E
4 - F - F
5 - C - C
6 - D - D
7 - G - G
8 - A - A
9 - C - C
10 - B - B
11 - D - D
12 - D - D
13 - D - D
14 - D - D
15 - H - H
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

One idea that I can think of is as follows:

Shuffle the assessors {1-9}. Then assign the first 4.5 items to them sequentially as per the result of this shuffle.

Then shuffle them again. Again assign them sequentially to the next items. If the first assessor happens to be the same one that is already assigned to the 5th item, then swap the 1st and second assessor in the list.

Keep doing this for all items.

Answer (score 0):

One way is with a collection class and embedded classes for the items and assessors.  Here's a partial implementation to show how the list could be generated:

```
Public Class MyItemCollection
    Class Assessor
        Public Name As String = ""
        Public Shared Operator <>(LH As Assessor, RH As Assessor) As Boolean
            Return LH.Name <> RH.Name
        End Operator
        Public Shared Operator =(LH As Assessor, RH As Assessor) As Boolean
            Return RH.Name = LH.Name
        End Operator
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return Name
        End Function
    End Class
    Class MyItem
        Public Name As String = ""
        Public Assessor1 As New Assessor
        Public Assessor2 As New Assessor
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return Name & " - " & Assessor1.ToString & " - " & Assessor2.ToString
        End Function
    End Class
    Private AssessorList As New List(Of Assessor)
    Private ItemList As New List(Of MyItem)
    Public Sub AddAssessor(Name As String)
        AssessorList.Add(New Assessor With {.Name = Name})
    End Sub
    Public Sub AddItem(Name As String)
        ItemList.Add(New MyItem With {.Name = Name})
    End Sub
    Private Rnd As New Random(Now.Millisecond * Now.Day * Now.Minute)
    Public Function AssignAssessors() As List(Of MyItem)
        Dim OutVal As New List(Of MyItem)
        Dim average As Integer = ((ItemList.Count \ AssessorList.Count) * 2) + 5
        Dim AssessorCount(AssessorList.Count - 1) As Integer
        For Each item As MyItem In ItemList
            Dim firstassessorindex As Integer
            Do
                firstassessorindex = Rnd.Next(0, AssessorList.Count)

            Loop Until AssessorCount(firstassessorindex) <= average
            item.Assessor1 = AssessorList(firstassessorindex)
            AssessorCount(firstassessorindex) += 1
            Dim secondassessorindex As Integer
            Do
                secondassessorindex = Rnd.Next(0, AssessorList.Count)

            Loop Until AssessorList(secondassessorindex) <> item.Assessor1 AndAlso AssessorCount(secondassessorindex) < average
            item.Assessor2 = AssessorList(secondassessorindex)
            AssessorCount(secondassessorindex) += 1
        Next
        OutVal = ItemList
        Return OutVal
    End Function
End Class
```

One thing that wasn't clear in your explanation was if the distribution between Assessor1 and Assessor2 is important(does it matter if an assessor is the second assessor more times than it is the first?).  If you need that, then a List(Of Tuple(Integer, Integer)) might be needed for the AssessorCount instead of a List(Of Integer)

The `ToString` method for each item in the return list will be in the format -

`ItemName - Assessor1Name - Assessor2Name`

Comment: Tried to implement what you put above and not getting anything good. All it seems to be doing is getting a random assessor and then assigning the same assessor in both spots. Please see my question edit for the code I used.

Comment: @TheTXI - Sorry had a couple of typos in there. It should work better now.

Comment: Before I had an opportunity to check back in here I managed to get a working proof of concept done myself. I'm almost afraid of going and trying yours now. I'll give it a whirl tomorrow morning and I'll also post my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your assignment rules, but this might be close.

```
var assessors = new []
{
    "A", "B", "C",
    "D", "E", "F",
    "G", "H", "I",
};

var rnd = new Random();

var query =
    from a1 in assessors
    from a2 in assessors
    where a1 != a2
    orderby rnd.Next()
    select new { a1, a2};

var results =
    Enumerable
        .Range(1, 477)
        .Zip(query
            .Repeat(),
            (i, aa) => new
            {
                Item = i,
                Assessor1 = aa.a1,
                Assessor2 = aa.a2,
            });
```

I get this kind of result:

```
  1  F  B
  2  E  C
  3  D  H
    ... 
476  F  C
477  B  E
```